# Express & Jade, templates adding code to the layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm playing around with an Express site with Node.JS

I have a layout file which, let's say, looks like this:

```
html
    title foo
body!= body
```

From what I have been able to understand, the output of the template is inserted into a variable called `body` and that's added to the layout there on the 3rd line. However, if I wanted a template to add, for example, a `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` element, how would I do that?

I did see the explanation of extending templates and using blocks, but I'm not sure how that ties it to using layouts. The templates themselves shouldn't be extending the layout, right? Or, does template inheritance remove the need for layouts at all? I would suspect not, but I'm not sure.

Also, since I'm here, how do you specify a different layout to be used, or for no layout to be used at all. Currently, the views are being rendered like this:

```
res.render('templateName', { myTemplateVars : 'foo' });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for was released 3 days ago.

http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/10695801204/jade-stylus-0-16-0-released

I have personally been using it for a few weeks and love the recent additions. The block statement allows you to specify default content and any extension template can override a named block.

Basically, blocks override, includes append and extends chooses your parent template.

Comment: ok, so in my case, the layout should have `block meta` and then nothing inside that, and then the template can write `block meta` and add whatever tags it wants?

Comment: Yep, block statements can be declared without nested content, acting as a content place holder. Inheriting templates can declare blocks without content as well but just watch out for clobbering parent blocks.

Comment: Grr... bad enter key :)

So, add the meta block and in your inheriting templates define the meta block and add whatever tags you want in the block for that template.

Also, drop the body variable and make it a block to be overridden in your child templates.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try [dust](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) template engine.
It is far more interesting and designer friendly.
In dust you can write base.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>kiss.js example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/css1.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/css2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js2.js"></script>
    {+head/}
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 100%">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>kiss.js example - {+header}{/header}</h1>
            {+header_buttons}{/header_buttons}
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            {+content}{/content}
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">made with kiss.js</td>
                    <td>{+footer_buttons}{/footer_buttons}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and view.html:

`{>base.html/}
{<content}
    <h2>name: {name}</h2>
    <h3>{foo}</h3>
    {#numbers}
        <div>{.}</div>
    {/numbers}
{/content}`

Comment: Can you paste how you configure app.js to use dust templates?